# Plotly Dash App Callback for Choropleth Map

Tags: callback, plotly-dash, choropleth

I have some problems with the callback function in plotly's dash. I want my choropleth map to update according to the selected year. The slider itself does work and the correct data is selected (checked that with the "print(filtered_df)" statement). However, the map is not updating accordingly and I just don't understand why. What am I missing?

Thanks for any help!

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.FLATLY])

app.layout = dbc.Container(html.Div([

    dbc.Row(
        [
            dcc.Graph(id='graph-with-slider'),
            dcc.Slider(
                min=df['year'].min(),
                max=df['year'].max(),
                step=None,
                value=df['year'].max(),
                marks={str(year): str(year) for year in df['year'].unique()},
                id='year-slider'
            )
        ]
    )
]))


@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='graph-with-slider', component_property='figure'),
    [Input(component_id='year-slider', component_property='value')]
)
def update_figure(selected_year):
    filtered_df = df.loc[df.year == selected_year].reset_index()
    #print(filtered_df)

    fig = px.choropleth(filtered_df, locations=df['Country Code'], locationmode='ISO-3',
                        color=df['life_expectancy_total'], color_continuous_scale=colorscale)
    fig.update_layout(transition_duration=500)
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: I think that maybe you are missing `geojson` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

... found the problem! I just wasn't calling on the right df in this part of code :/

`fig = px.choropleth(filtered_df, locations=df['Country Code'], locationmode='ISO-3', color=df['life_expectancy_total'], color_continuous_scale=colorscale)`

should have been:

`fig = px.choropleth(filtered_df, locations=filtered_df['Country Code'], locationmode='ISO-3', color=filtered_df.life_expectancy_avg, color_continuous_scale=colorscale)`